# restore database using data file

Tags: php, apache, wamp, database-backups

Had overwritten data folder from wamp bin directory when I re-installed the apache. Is there any possible way to retrieve my data from previous apache. I have my back up which is a '.data' file. How am I goin' to restore it? Please badly need help. Thanks

Comment: aiaiaiaiiiiiii :))) , +1 Interesting!

Comment: Apache is not a database engine and MySQL does not use the `.data` extension as far as I know. You've lost some data and you don't know where it comes from?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a file recovery program as explained here: http://lifehacker.com/393084/how-to-recover-deleted-files-with-free-software
So long as you haven't saved files over those, you should be able to recover them. Then you have to put them back where they belong. This may be difficult without a good understanding of the file structure, and since you didn't specify which database, I can't give you any further help on that front. Good luck!